# C++ anonymous struct call failed

Tags: c++, struct, anonymous-types

This code failed at run time and not at compile time.  I am not expert in C++.
Any help?

```
extern void fn();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    fn();
}

void fn()
{
    struct Foo{
        string name;
    }*foo;
    foo->name="sleiman";
    cout<<foo->name<<endl;
}
```

Why does this code fail at run time and why does it succeed if I create a static instance?

```
void fn()
{
    struct Foo{
        string name;
    }foo;
    foo.name="sleiman";
    cout<<foo.name<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foo` is made to be a pointer but is not initialised so when you try to access name it is reading invalid memory. You initialise `foo` as a pointer to a `Foo` struct but do not tell it to point to an actual object so is in effect a loose pointer.

In order to make this work you will need to make the pointer point to an actual object by using the `new` keyword or some other means.

Comment: It is a method of creating an object on the stack and returns a pointer to that object which in a way is initialising the pointer.

Comment: Yeah but my point is that the problem isn't that he needs to initialize the pointer. The problem is that he needs to instantiate an object. You can initialize the pointer to null and he'll still get a runtime error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in your first example you are making a pointer to foo. Just because you make a pointer to foo doesn't mean it actually points to an object. You have to use new to create that object. Try this:

```
void fn()
{
    struct Foo{
        string name;
    };
    Foo* foo = new Foo;
    foo->name="sleiman";
    cout<<foo->name<<endl;
    delete foo;
}
```

Make sure you delete it when you're done using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Foo{
    string name;
}*foo;
```

`foo` is just declared as a pointer to `Foo`, but it is not pointing any real object. You need to create an instance using **new** and then you can access it's members. It's more like -

```
int *ptr;
(*ptr) = 100;   // Can you do this with out ptr pointing to a valid resource ?
```

But in the other case, you have real object itself.

Comment: this is true, but why it doesn't display garbage data as usual in c++

Comment: The behavior is undefined. It's not guaranteed to have garbage and also to fail at run time.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a pointer to X, you are not actually allocating an X, and your pointer is pointing somewhere off in space.  You either need to assign the pointer to point a pre-existing instance of X, or allocate a new one with `new X`.  Otherwise, you are accessing memory which you don't know what it's for.  And that's Undefined Behavior, so anything can happen.